# SQL Server to SYnapse SQL syntax modifications

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I have a query that works just fine in SQL Server but I would like some help with the required syntax modifications to make it work at Synapse SQL. Any help would be appreciated! The id's are unix timestamps. I want to count the id's of the previous day filtering by time range using the unix timestamps

```
SELECT COUNT(Id)
FROM [dbo].[name]
WHERE Id >= CONVERT(bigint, DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', CONVERT(date,dateadd(d, -1, GETDATE()))))*1000 
          and Id < CONVERT(bigint, DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', CONVERT(date,GETDATE())))*1000
```

Comment: If it's not working on Azure Synapse, it would be helpful if you explain why it isn't.

Comment: I don't know why it isnt working. It produces an empty column, no errors

Comment: You might want to check what values you are getting from your expressions then (such as `CONVERT(bigint, DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', CONVERT(date,dateadd(d, -1, GETDATE()))))*1000`). Perhaps the values being returned aren't what you expect. For example, Azure Services (normally) operate in UTC, so `GETDATE()` could be giving a completely different value to what you get locally. If the value of your epoch isn't UTC based, then your query isn't going to give you the result back you expect.

Comment: Could you share with sample input ids?

Comment: Sure an example of an id is: 1622079015031

Comment: Check if `SELECT GETDATE()` query returns same value in SQL server and Synapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When SQL servers and Azure Synapse are in different time zones, the results of Query will be varying. Azure Synapse will be in UTC time zone.

In order to convert current date value to local datetime value in azure synapse, User defined function is created as in below script.

```sql
Create  FUNCTION [dbo].[CurrentLocalTime]( @TimeZoneName sysname )
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
RETURN DATEADD(hour, 
                 TRY_CAST((SELECT REPLACE(current_utc_offset, N':', N'.')
                           FROM sys.time_zone_info
                           WHERE [name] = @TimeZoneName) AS decimal(18,2)), 
                 SYSDATETIME());
END;
```

Instead of using getdate() of function, the above function is used in the query.

**Query**

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM sample1
WHERE Id >= CONVERT(bigint, DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', CONVERT(date,dateadd(d, -1, dbo.CurrentLocalTime('AUS Eastern Standard Time' )))))*1000 
and Id < CONVERT(bigint, DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', CONVERT(date,dbo.CurrentLocalTime('AUS Eastern Standard Time' ))))*1000
```

The time zone can be replaced in the query as per the requirement.

**Results** for Sample data:

[image]